# How do I supplement a row with information from another row?

Tags: r

I have the following problem. I have a dataframe in R of the following form.

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                 question=c("Who is your favorite singer?",NA,NA,NA,"Who is your favorite actor?", NA, NA, NA, "Who is your favorite athlete?", NA, NA, NA),
                 answer=c(NA,"Michael Jackson","Taylor Swift","Celine Dion", NA, "Brad Pitt", "Julia Roberts", "Hugh Grant", NA, "Michael Jordan", "Dirk Nowitzki", "Mike Tyson"))
```

I need to change the dataframe in order to replace the NA-values with the question from the row with the same ID and the row that just contains information on the question can be dropped. That means:

```
df_neu <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                     question=c("Who is your favorite singer?","Who is your favorite singer?","Who is your favorite singer?", "Who is your favorite actor?", "Who is your favorite actor?", "Who is your favorite actor?", "Who is your favorite athlete?", "Who is your favorite athlete?", "Who is your favorite athlete?"), 
                     answer=c("Michael Jackson","Taylor Swift","Celine Dion", "Brad Pitt", "Julia Roberts", "Hugh Grant", "Michael Jordan", "Dirk Nowitzki", "Mike Tyson"))
```

I am a beginner in R. Therefore, I do not really have an idea on how to start.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: could you provide your target data frame, as well?

Comment: df_neu would be the target data frame. r2evans answer helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```r
df$question <- zoo::na.locf(df$question)
df
#    id                      question          answer
# 1   1  Who is your favorite singer?            <NA>
# 2   1  Who is your favorite singer? Michael Jackson
# 3   1  Who is your favorite singer?    Taylor Swift
# 4   1  Who is your favorite singer?     Celine Dion
# 5   2   Who is your favorite actor?            <NA>
# 6   2   Who is your favorite actor?       Brad Pitt
# 7   2   Who is your favorite actor?   Julia Roberts
# 8   2   Who is your favorite actor?      Hugh Grant
# 9   3 Who is your favorite athlete?            <NA>
# 10  3 Who is your favorite athlete?  Michael Jordan
# 11  3 Who is your favorite athlete?   Dirk Nowitzki
# 12  3 Who is your favorite athlete?      Mike Tyson

df <- df[!is.na(df$answer),]
df
#    id                      question          answer
# 2   1  Who is your favorite singer? Michael Jackson
# 3   1  Who is your favorite singer?    Taylor Swift
# 4   1  Who is your favorite singer?     Celine Dion
# 6   2   Who is your favorite actor?       Brad Pitt
# 7   2   Who is your favorite actor?   Julia Roberts
# 8   2   Who is your favorite actor?      Hugh Grant
# 10  3 Who is your favorite athlete?  Michael Jordan
# 11  3 Who is your favorite athlete?   Dirk Nowitzki
# 12  3 Who is your favorite athlete?      Mike Tyson
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a little bit of `dplyr` and `tidyr`, you can fill the question column downward (the default for the `.direction` argument), then filter for rows with non-`NA` answers.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::fill(question) %>%
  filter(!is.na(answer))
#>   id                      question          answer
#> 1  1  Who is your favorite singer? Michael Jackson
#> 2  1  Who is your favorite singer?    Taylor Swift
#> 3  1  Who is your favorite singer?     Celine Dion
#> 4  2   Who is your favorite actor?       Brad Pitt
#> 5  2   Who is your favorite actor?   Julia Roberts
#> 6  2   Who is your favorite actor?      Hugh Grant
#> 7  3 Who is your favorite athlete?  Michael Jordan
#> 8  3 Who is your favorite athlete?   Dirk Nowitzki
#> 9  3 Who is your favorite athlete?      Mike Tyson
```